# Batch file run before the windows 7 system starts to boot

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, batch-file, win10-fast-startup

I need to start batch file with windows 7 at the same time.

Edit:

I'm trying to press some key combinations, the moment the system starts to boot, because I only have access to the telnet remotely

Comment: This smacks of [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) Start by telling us what you are trying to achieve, rather than how you think you need to achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure if you can run it on the startup with Windows, since batch files are running on a software that is probally loaded after the startup of windows, but you can still run the batch on user login.

Comment: I'm trying to press some key combinations, the moment the system starts to boot, because I only have access to the telnet remotely

Comment: You never mentioned telnet in your question. How are we meant to guess what it is you are trying to achieve if you only ask about what you think might be a way to achieve it? We're right back to this being an XY Problem. Please edit your original question appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot push buttons at boot using Batch. It just isn't the right tool for the job.

If this is a virtual machine you might be able to script key presses from the host.

If this is a physical machine you'll need some sort of "Out Of Band" management tool that allows remote access at the pre-boot level.